# Hide close button to banner of Popup mailchimp in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, popup, mailchimp

in my wordpress site's I implement a mailchimp popup subscribers. I need to hide the close button in the banner who the code display before the mailchimp form in mobile view. Anyone can help me? I try to add custom css to my wordpress theme with

```css
.bannerContent__closeButton {
  display:none;
}
```

but not work. Can anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a link to your site? If your custom css code isn't working then double check your close button class. You can find it by inspecting it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try and get more specific. A link to your content or some more code would help, but basically,

```
body div.yourContainer div.yourRow div.bannerContent__closeButton {
  display:none;
}
```

This way you override the default. If you can, right click the close button, select inspect element, and then the computed tab in Chrome. This will show you the 'display' attribute and you can see what is taking presidence.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the above won't work is because the popup form is within an iframe hosted by MailChimp. You're writing CSS outside of the iframe, which does not apply to the content within the iframe.

Your only option here is to build your own popup form (or find one that someone else has built that you can modify). This will require both some client-side JavaScript as well as a server-side component to make the API calls, since the MailChimp API calls do not support cross-origin requests (CORS). See https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/.